# Blank windows in some apps in macOS as guest OS in Parallels virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, parallels-desktop

When running Parallels 12.2.0 with macOS Sierra as the guest OS, I see windows that are blank, partially blank, or scaled improperly (zoomed in, magnified) in some apps such as non-Safari web browsers (Firefox, Opera, etc.). The behavior is consistent, either working properly all the time or improperly all the time.

I am guessing that apps handling their own window-drawing rather calling upon Apple's usual drawing libraries is the cause of the bug.

Is there any trick to getting the contents of these apps’ windows to appear correctly?

## Bad

### Brave 0.18.14 browser

[image: screen shot of Brave browser with its window drawn partially missing due to Retina mode in a Parallels 12 VM]

### Firefox 54.0.1

[image]

## Good

In contrast, some apps including some web browsers draw properly.

## Safari 10.1.2 browser

[image: screen shot of Safari 10.1.2 drawing properly]

## Vivaldi 1.6.689.40 browser

[image: screen shot of Vivaldi browser drawing properly]

Comment: Just to clarify, is this happening with apps _within_ the virtual machine?

Comment: @Monomeeth Yes, window-drawing fails in a few particular apps running *inside* the virtual machine, as stated in the title of this Question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your guess is correct no - there's no requirement to use Apple's drawing libraries for stuff to work in Parallels.

However, it does seem likely that these programs that don't work are 3D-accelerated and you have problems with 3D-acceleration (which is a known problem-area for programs like Parallels). Therefore try disabling 3D acceleration in the Parallels settings for the virtual machine, reboot the virtual machine and your programs should work again.

Comment: I see no 3D or hardware-acceleration options in either the Control Center preferences nor in the preferences for my macOS guest VM in Parallels 12.2.1. Please describe or show the setting you have in mind. As I understand it, Parallels does not support 3D hardware acceleration for macOS as the guest OS.

Comment: @BasilBourque Where do you have that understanding from? - Do you have a link? (I'm not doubting that you're correct, just want to make sure you're not looking at outdated docs)